# Найти самого похожего пользователя

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, вектор

Необходимо найти самого похожего пользователя. Посчитать косинусное сходство между этим пользователем и всеми пользователями из массива user_stats

Имеется матрица покупок в интернет-магазине. Столбец А - ID пользователя. Остальные столбцы - количество покупок категорий товаров этим пользователем.
Матрица в виде numpy array:

```
users_stats = np.array(
    [
        [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0],
        [2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 4]
    ], 
    np.int32
)
```

На сайт заходит очередной посетитель, о покупках которого известно следующее:

```
next_user_stats = np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0])
```

Необходимо найти самого похожего пользователя. Т. е. посчитайте косинусное сходство между этим пользователем и всеми пользователями из массива user_stats. В задании нудно использовать библиотеку numpy.

Есть решение для похожего примера, но в нем нет списка в списке и поэтому он не работает на данной задаче:

```
def cosine( users_stats, next_user_stats ):
    # длины векторов
    users_stats_Length = np.linalg.norm( users_stats )
    next_user_stats_Length = np.linalg.norm( next_user_stats )
    
    return np.dot( users_stats, next_user_stats ) / ( users_stats_Length * next_user_stats_Length )
```

Вот результат:

```
cosine( users_stats, next_user_stats )

array([0.04688072, 0.23440362, 0.09376145, 0.23440362, 0.09376145,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.14064217, 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно применить `cosine` к каждой строке матрицы `users_stats`. В numpy для этого есть функция `apply_along_axis`:

```
muls = np.apply_along_axis(cosine, 1, users_stats, next_user_stats)
```

Второй аргумент `1` означает, что функция `cosine` должна вызываться для строк. Последний аргумент `next_user_stats` будет подставляться вторым аргументом в `cosine`. Вызов этой функции эквивалентен вот какому коду на Python:

```
muls = np.array([cosine(row, next_user_stats) for row in users_stats])
```

В обоих случаях результат равен

```
array([0.2       , 0.84515425, 0.4       , 0.79056942, 0.4       ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.9486833 , 0.        , 0.        ])
```

Функция `np.argmax` находит индекс элемента, который соответствует максимальному значению массива (нумерация с нуля):

```
best_user = np.argmax(muls)
```

Наилучшее совпадение - пользователь номер 7.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутое пояснение